# How to load JSON objectives in portions with jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I was wondering how I can show the first five items of my JSON object by using jQuery Ajax and if the button `#load` is clicked, there will be load 5 more each time. Without `if(i <= 4){}` statement, all my items of the JSON object are loaded in the page.

With the if statement it shows me the first for objects of the `JSON`. I was trying to create a click event as you can see, that will switch a boolean `load more` to `true`, if the button is clicked, but I don't know how to go further to achieve this. Also I want to add support for scrolling down the page to load content..

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'api/videoData.js',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                // console.log(data); //uncomment this for debug
                // root.dataArr = data;
                Triptube.dataController.timelineEvents(data);

                var index = 0;
                var loadmore = false;
                var el = $('.featured'); // .featured

                $.get('directives/format-text.html', function(response){
                    console.log('succes');
                })

                .done(function (response) {
                    // console.dir(response);

                    var raw_model = response;

                    for (var i = 0; i < raw_model.length; i++) {

                        if (i <= 4) {
                            model = $(raw_model);
                            model.find('h4').html(data.content[i].subtitle);
                            model.find('h3').html(data.content[i].title);
                            model.find('p').html(data.content[i].text);
                            $('.featured').append(model);
                        }

                        if (loadmore) {
                            console.log('Clicked');
                            loadmore = false;
                        }

                    }

                    $('#loadmore').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        loadmore = true;
                    });

                })

                .fail(function (response) {
                    console.dir(response);                  
                });


            },

            error: function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
                console.log('Houston, we have a problem!');
            }


        });
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "title":    "London",
    "category": "The Ultimate",
    "image":    "images/content/londen.jpg",
    "website":  "http://www.london.nl/",
    "youtube":  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq9rjbouBlY&t=23",
    "maps":     "https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Londen,+Verenigd+Koninkrijk/@51.5114089,-0.1271477,13.79z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99",
    "content":  [
        {
            "type" :        "normal",
            "timeTrigger":  24,
            "title":        "London Eye",
            "subtitle":     "Algemene",
            "picture" :     "images/content/london.jpg",
            "text":         "This is the London Eye",
            "readmore":     "http://wikitravel.org/en/London"
        },{
            "type":         "normal",
            "timeTrigger":  24,
            "title":        "Sherlock Holmes",
            "subtitle":     "Detective",
            "picture" :     "images/content/sherlock_holmes.jpg",
            "text":         "Sherlock Holmes is een fictieve detective  <br> uit de verhalen van de laat-19de-eeuwse",
            "readmore":     "http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes"
        },{
            "type":         "normal",
            "timeTrigger":  39,
            "title":        "Fish \"n Chips",
            "subtitle":     "Eten",
            "picture" :     "images/content/sherlock_holmes.jpg",
            "text":         "Fish and chips is een typisch Britse afhaalmaaltijd .",
            "readmore":     "http://youngandfoodish.com/london/top-10-fish-and-chips-in-london/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Look out for some advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First step would be to stop sending an ajax request on each click, because you've got all the data you need after the first click.

Comment: You could override `for (var i = 0; i < raw_model.length; i++)` to go from 0 to 4 instead of through the length of the AJAX array. But since, as Kevin pointed out, you have already retrieved all the data, there is nothing else to do here. *Perhaps if you had a service for retrieving data, you could pass a `lastItemReceived` to start at a particular index...*

Comment: So with this setup it's not possible?

Comment: put them all in the dom and think of `loadMore` as being simply `showMore`. Otherwise modify backend to only send what you want and keep track of what's been sent already